# Use scala Type to set type parameter (thru TypeTag?)

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, type-parameter

I'd like to dynamically insert a type parameter, i.e. `List[T]`, where T can only be found at run-time.

Normally you can create bindings like this if you already have an existing type parameter `T` (not the case), or during run-time using `TypeTag`s.

The latter sounds like the way to go, but this shifts the question to "how do I get my TypeTag here".

I know how to create a TypeTag using if you have your type `T` (`typeTag[T]`), or if you have an instance of your type `T` (see `getTypeTag` below).

However, I have neither; what I do have of my type in question is a `reflect.runtime.universe.Type`. Might it be possible to convert this into a `TypeTag` so I can dynamically insert my type parameter?

Bonus points if the `List` can be made dynamic as well.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

scala> def getTypeTag[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeTag[T]

scala> def insertTag[T](tt: ru.TypeTag[T]) = List[T]_

scala> val fn = (a: String) => "foo"
fn: String => String = <function1>

scala> val pars = getTypeTag(fn).tpe.typeArgs.init(0)
pars: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String

scala> insertTag(pars)
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : reflect.runtime.universe.Type
 required: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[?]
       insertTag(pars)
                 ^
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the expected result of `insertTag(pars)`. Do you always expect `fn` to have a single parameter, or can it have multiple parameters? What would be the expected result then?

Comment: Good question, guess these were bits I'd been trying to simplify out. In reality I'm actually getting the `TypeTag` for `fn.tupled`, which takes care of multiple parameters.

In reality the output is not `List[T]` but a `akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[T]`, which is useful just like that unlike `List[T]` (hence I had to add the `_`, without it it's nothing and errors).

That `insertTag` function works if you put in an actual `TypeTag` (i.e. `insertTag(ru.typeTag[Integer])`), though now to make it work with only a `Type` to go by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to convert a `Type` to `TypeTag`. If your goal is to get `TypeTag` just for function parameters, you can modify your function `getTypeTag` to accept functions:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
def getTypeTag[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: (T) => Any) = ru.typeTag[T]
def insertTag[T](tt: ru.TypeTag[T]) = List[T] _

val fn = (a: String, b: Int) => "foo"
var parTypeTag = getTypeTag(fn.tupled)
insertTag(parTypeTag) // Seq[(String, Int)] => List[(String, Int)] = <function1>
```